# Fatal error: Class 'sfGuardSecurityUser' not found in ...\lib\myUser.class.php on line 4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I get that error

> Fatal error: Class 'sfGuardSecurityUser' not found in...\lib\myUser.class.php on line 4

this is my setting.yml

```
all:
  .settings:

    csrf_secret:            unCodeSecret
    enabled_modules:        [default, sfGuardAuth]
    escaping_strategy:      true
    escaping_method:        ESC_SPECIALCHARS
    use_database:           true

  .actions:

    login_module: sfGuardAuth
    login_action: signin`
```

and myUser.class

```
class myUser extends sfGuardSecurityUser
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow each steps from [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin/4_0_2?tab=plugin_readme)?

Did you clear your cache?

```
php symfony cc
```

Did you enable the plugin in `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` ?

```
$this->enablePlugins(array(
  'sfDoctrinePlugin',
  'sfDoctrineGuardPlugin',
  // ...
```

Comment: Sure you didn't. At least, not all the part. Did you build your model?

Comment: i added 'sfDoctrineGuardPlugin' but i got 3 other errors :               1 - SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for                              2 - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The plugin "sfDoctrineGuardPlugin" does not exist.' in...\lib\vendor\symfony-1.4.18\lib\config\sfProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 460             3 -  InvalidArgumentException: The plugin "sfDoctrineGuardPlugin" does not exist. in .....\lib\vendor\symfony-1.4.18\lib\config\sfProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 460

Comment: Did you install the plugin in `/plugins` (using svn or `symfony plugin:install sfGuardPlugin`) ?

Comment: sorry i said i did , cause i've recieved just the "clear cach"

Comment: i installed the plugin by downloading it from the officiel website , and i did extract in plugins file

Comment: i also executed that command : php symfony doctrine:build-all-reload

Comment: There is no `build-all-reload` in the readme file. So I guess you didn't follow each step from the readme file. So please, take few minutes to read the whole readme file and perform each action described. It then should works like a charm.

Comment: build-all-reload frontend existes in readme file . i've corrected routing.yml and all the other instructions , but these 3 errors still exist

Comment: Could you update your question with the folder that are in your plugins folder, please?

Comment: okey , i have sfDoctrineGuardPlugin folder , in which i have config , data,lib,i18n,and modules which contains : sfguardauth , sfguardforgotpassword , sfguardgroup , sfguardpermission , sfguardregister and sfguarduser

Comment: i think that the problem is in ...\lib\vendor\symfony-1.4.18\lib\config\sfProjectConfiguration.class.php , it cant' find that plugin , do u think that i had problem while installing the plugin ?

Comment: Did you edit this file?! You should edit `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`

Comment: this is the line that causes that error : `throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The plugin "%s" does not exist.', $plugin));`

Comment: in that function : `public function getPluginPaths()
  {
    if (!isset($this->pluginPaths['']))
    {
      $pluginPaths = $this->getAllPluginPaths();

      $this->pluginPaths[''] = array();
      foreach ($this->getPlugins() as $plugin)
      {
        if (isset($pluginPaths[$plugin]))
        {
          $this->pluginPaths[''][] = $pluginPaths[$plugin];
        }
        else
        {
          throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The plugin "%s" does not exist.', $plugin));
        }
      }
    }

    return $this->pluginPaths[''];
  }`

Comment: ok ! the problem is solved , while installing the plugin , some files were missing . i added them and it works now , thank you for your help :)